# How can I (statically) analyze java code and extract actual parameter values in constructors or methods?

Tags: java, static-analysis

I would like to have a tool which finds all the occurrences of a (Java) constructor/method and reports the actual parameter values for each invocation.

I guess there's not something already prepared and also that I will need Static Analysis.

Which library/program do you suggest to use ?

(I have to analyse Java code but can use any language to write the analyser)

Comment: Do you mean statically determining the variables at runtime? What would you do with IO data (user input, files, etc.) and System data (v.g., system time)?

Comment: IntelliJ can tell you if a method is never called or an argument is only ever given the same value.  It doesn't tell you if there are multiple possible values, but it might be a start.

Comment: @SJuan76 In my case values are never by I/O. Anyway I don't need (to build?) a perfect tool, but something that is able to resolve constants, simple string operation, and (simple) calls.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I need to build a report for hundreds of calls. I can't do it manually. Ideally I would build a specified tool starting from some pre-existent libraries.

Comment: @OGrandeDiEnne IntelliJ will do it for all your code by default (or a portion of it) and provides some quick fixes which mean you are likely to correct it.  If you generate a long report, it can still be tedious to manually fix all the code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't want to fix anything. As output, I just want the list of actual parameter values for a specific method/constructor. I also want this analysis to be repeatable. Therefore, lot of manual work is not a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AspectJ. Define a Pointcut on constructors. Then write an aspect to execute on each invocation. Then apply the aspect to the entire project.

The code inside your aspect is given details to the call chain so you can interrogate the parameters yourself and log them anyway you want.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I never programmed in AspectJ. Do I have to modify the original code in order to run the aspect ?

Comment: No you don't need to alter your code. That's one of the big bonuses with using it. You could build it along side your development builds and exclude it from your production builds. I have a feeling that the Eclipse Project uses it to get timing metrics on their API method calls. Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ it should give you plenty of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool that can parse Java, builds an AST capturing the code (so you can search the code for method calls), can resolve type and names (so you know the meaning of each symbol instance and can determine that a specific identifier names the method(s) of interest, not just a symbol with accidentally the same name),  and can help you generate the method call.

The Java compiler offers APIs to support some of this.  I don't know that it will help you regenerate the method call text.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit provides general program analysis and transformation capabilities, including parsing, AST building/visiting, symbol table construction, and prettyprinting (regeneration of text) for arbitrary subtrees.  It has a full Java front end providing full name and type resolution.   It would be pretty straightforward to code an accurate, reliable tool to do what you want with the support DMS provides.